# What is the flow of the learning process within a neural network with respect to batch size and epochs?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, theano

I am confused with the happenings within the neural network with respect to terms like *batch size, epochs* and the distribution of weights among the process.

I want to validate if my understanding of the flow is valid according to the following order?

```
Considering one training/data point has 8 features(8 input nodes).
I have 20 training/data points.
I choose batch size of 2.
Now I want to make the model learn.
```

Executing first epoch

```
Executing first batch

    Data point-1 :8 feature's values go through the 8 input nodes.
        Random weights are initialised
        Forward Propagation happens
        Backward Propagation happens
        The result of backward propagation-all the weights are updated.

    Data point-2 :8 feature's values go through the 8 input nodes.
        Forward propagation happens with the updated weights found from the previous(aka Data point-1) back propagation result.
        Backward propagation happens and all the weights are again updated.

Executing second batch

    Data point-3 :8 features go through the 8 input nodes.
        Forward propagation happens with the updated nodes found from the previous(aka  Data point-2) back propagation result
        Backward propagation happens and all the weights are again updated.

This process continues………….until the first epoch ends
```

Executing the second epoch

```
Executing the second batch
    Data point-1: 8 feature's value go through 8 input nodes.
        No random weights this time. Forward propagation happens with the last back-propagated values found(from the First Epoch, last executed batch)
        Backward propagation happens and all the weights are again updated.

This process continues.. until the second epoch ends.
```

The process continues until the desired epoch.

Comment: The batch processing is wrong: For a batch we compute the gradients of the entire batch at once, then we sum all the gradients and then update the weights once per batch.

Comment: @vijaym i thought back propagation is the way to calculate gradient descent. If we calculate the backprop then automatically the new weights would be updated, isn't that the case?

Comment: Not sure i understand what you are saying, Think it as mini-batch forward pass, mini-batch backward pass and then then sum the gradients calculated during backward pass anf then update the weights. In the case, you are iterating over single sample in the batch, that is  not the case.

Comment: @vijaym so if i understand you correctly , you are saying first I compute the forward pass for all the data points within the mini batch and then compute backward pass on all the data points within the mini batch.This would give me N number of gradients.Where N is the batch size. I sum the gradients calculated and update the weights for each data point. Now for each data points I have different weights. So which weight do I pass to the next batch?

Comment: There are no different weights for each data point, they are the same for  all the data points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mini-batch` processing is wrong: For a batch we compute the gradients of the entire batch at once, then we sum all the gradients and then update the weights once per batch.

Here is the code that illustrates the gradient computation `d(loss)/d(W)` of the simple example: `y = W * x` for a `mini-batch` and a `single` input:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

W1 = tf.constant([[0.2]], dtype=tf.float32)
out = tf.matmul(X, W1)

loss = tf.square(out-Y)
#Calculate error gradient with respect to weights.
gradients = tf.gradients(loss, W1)[0]

with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

#Giving individual inputs
print(sess.run([gradients], {X: np.array([[0.1]]), Y:[[0.05]]})) 
# [[-0.006]]
print(sess.run([gradients], {X: np.array([[0.2]]), Y:[[0.1]]}))  
#[[-0.024]]

#Give a batch combining the above inputs
print(sess.run([gradients], {X: np.array([[0.1],[0.2]]), Y:[[0.05], [0.1]]}))   
# [[-0.03]] which is the sum of the above gradients.
```

Answer (score 0):

The steps you mention are for stochastic gradient descent where the batchsize is not playing any role..as the weights are updated after each data points and used in next data point evaluation.

For a min-batch scenario like batch size=2, it should calculate the new weights(via backprop.) together and then use them in the next batch(of size 2) and continue till culmination of all batches. The other things you mention are correct.

Comment: How would it 'calculate the new weights(via backprop.) together' ?

Comment: Apart from the links and details provided, this link https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/9zJUs/mini-batch-gradient-descent may also be helpful. In short, calculate the gradient for each data point and then calculate an average of all gradients in the batch and update the weights like: weight1(new) = weight1(old) - learning rate* average gradient.

Answer (score 0):

You've got almost everything right,but the backpropagation weight update. The error is computed for each sample in the mini batch, but the weights are only updated once all the samples from the mini batch have gone through forward propagation. You can read more about it [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-mini-batch-gradient-descent-configure-batch-size/)

Comment: I am struggling to find what is happening sequentially/the flow of the process. Is this the right understanding-For every data point in each batch first all the forward passes are calculated. Then the backprop is done. But backprop would update the weights anyways..so what is going on?

Comment: For each data point the forward pass and gradient are computed. Then the gradient can be summed or averaged and based on this new gradient, the network weights are updated. This prevents big changes in the weights if you have outliers, speeds the process and can make the network more generelizable.

Comment: after the network weights are updated, each data point would have its own 'updated weights'. What weights would be passed to the next batch then?